# If statement not changing value of a variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to create some variables to use for HSL colors in Three.js. I want to make sure they are not too dark or too light, so I created some if statements to check/change the variable if the numbers are out of my range.

I don't want the value to be below 0.1 or above 0.9. But it doesn't appear to be changing the variables and I can't figure out why.

```
color1h = (data[0] / 359);
color1s = (data[1] / 255);
color1l = (data[2] / 255);

if (color1s < 0.1){color1s += 0.1;}
if (color1s > 0.9){color1s -= 0.1;}
if (color1l < 0.1){color1s += 0.1;}
if (color1l > 0.9){color1s -= 0.1;}
console.log(color1h, color1s, color1l);
```

Comment: This is what the console log shows: 
0.07799442896935933 0.17058823529411762 0.9333333333333333

the last number should be less than .9

Comment: Your code checks `color1l` and `color1s` but the changes are only made to `color1s`, according to the code you posted.

Comment: @Pointy That's it! Thank you so much. I couldn't see it.